# Fuji 35mm 1.4 stuck in manual focus mode?

Tags: autofocus

I know that to go into autofocus mode the lens ring needs to be pulled out.  However mine is completely stuck!  I am a member of the Fuji VIP program and have received a faulty lens before.  I got this Fuji XF 35mm 1.4 lens 2 years ago but rarely use autofocus.  My first time playing with it and I realize the focus ring is completely stuck and will not pull out to autofocus mode.  Any suggestions?  I have no idea how to fix this if it is even fixable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is the Fujinon XF 35mm f/1.4 R I think you change the focus mode with the camera body auto/manual switch. I see no reference to a push-pull operation in the lens manual or online reviews...

Comment: I used to have a copy of the XF 35/1.4. It does not have a clutch mechanism. There is an AF/MF switch on most FujiFilm X-series bodies. Some X-A bodies don't have the switch.

Comment: Hi thank you you are right BobT!  The Fuji XF 35mm 1.4 does not have the pull out mechanism.  I was in auto mode on my camera but did not have PRE-AF turned on my settings.  Apologies that my lens and camera specifications were not clear.  Thank you both!